# Bootstrap adjust section height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there anyway to reduce the height of a section being displayed in bootstrap?

I want to make a section 3/4 of the height so the content below is visible on the same screen

all the sections take up the whole length of the screen at the moment.

```
<!-- Intro Section -->
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-lg-12 main_text">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 ">
                    <img class="logofirst" src="../logo/logo.png">
                </div>    

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>





<!-- About Section -->
<section id="about" class="about-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class= "col-lg-12 panel-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    <h1>OUR MISSION: </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <div class ="col-lg-4">
                <h1>TO CARE</h1>
                <IMG class = "icons" SRC="icons/heart.png">
                <P class="icontext">WE ARE HERE TO HELP, ADVISE AND TO LISTEN 
                </p>
                </div>
                <div class ="col-lg-4">
                <h1>TO INSPIRE</h1>
                <IMG class = "icons" SRC="icons/hat.png">
                <P class="icontext">PROVIDING VERY HIGH CALIBRE PRODUCTS.</P>

                </div>
                <div class ="col-lg-4">
                <h1>TO PROVIDE</h1>
                <IMG class = "icons" SRC="icons/box.png">
                </P>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Services Section -->
<section id="services" class="services-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Fundraising Goal:</h1>
                <h2 class="fundraise">$5,000</h2>
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 1%;">
                            1%
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    A total of <b class="donation_amount">$0.00</b> has been raised so far.
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What section do you want to adjust the height of? Please include enough of your code to provide an applicable assessment.

Comment: @Ryan done. of the first intro section

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of different ways to do this:

1. Set a height/max-height for the `.logofirst` element and limit the content in the intro section.
2. Set a height/max-height on the `#intro` div.

Ultimately, the route that you go depends entirely on your end goal and the content which will reside on the page.